# Unable to access Jenkins server

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to install [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on my web server, which is an Ubuntu 13.10 server running on an Amazon EC2 instance. I've restarted Jenkins using

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

When I check my processes with

```
ps aux | grep jenkins
```

I can see multiple items running with the following descriptions:

```
jenkins  22356  0.0  0.0  20268   400 ?        S    10:10   0:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --ajp13ListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --preferredClassLoader=java.net.URLClassLoader
jenkins  22358  5.9  5.7 1618372 97376 ?       Sl   10:10   0:17 /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/run/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1 --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --ajp13ListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --preferredClassLoader=java.net.URLClassLoader
```

The server doesn't want to allow me to access this installation, so if I visit

```
x.x.x.x:8080
```

I just get a "**Oops! Google Chrome could not connect**" page, not even a HTTP status 404 / 500.

I tried checking */var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log*, but it doesn't indicate any problems. Here's the log output after restarting:

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:07 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:13 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8080
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:13 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:14 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:14 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:14 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:14 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:14 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:22 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:23 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:23 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 43315
Dec 02, 2013 10:10:23 AM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

I was thinking I could be having a problem with EC2 security groups blocking the port, but my security group assigned to that server has got 8080 port opened for HTTP inbound.

Another check I tried was to SSH into the server, and use Lynx to see if Jenkins is actually serving content. I visited `http://localhost:8080` and it was showing the Jenkins page as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

If running Jenkins on an Amazon EC2 instance, try setting `HTTP_HOST` to `0.0.0.0`. You may not be able to bind the public interface IP directly.

---

**EDIT 1**

Check `/etc/default/jenkins` instead if you installed directly from the `.deb` package.

---

It appears Jenkins is listening on localhost (`--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1`). In this configuration, Jenkins is not listening for connections from the network interface.

To resolve for Ubuntu, check the contents of `/etc/init/jenkins.conf` and append `--httpListenAddress=x.x.x.x` to `JENKINS_ARGS` (where `x.x.x.x` is the server's external IP address).

Comment: Cool, I changed HTTP_HOST to the correct IP address, but it causes SEVERE: Container startup failed, Failed to listen on port 8080 and Cannot assign requested address errors when restarting. :(

Comment: Should I try installing OpenJDK instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710095/severe-failed-to-initialize-jenkins

Comment: Could be EC2 networking weirdness. Try setting `HTTP_HOST` to `0.0.0.0`, does that help?

Comment: I tried 0.0.0.0 as well, but I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Awesome, 0.0.0.0 fixed it! If you update your question, I'll accept. Thanks for the help! ;)